# D3.js Dynamic connector between objects

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, connector

I'm very new to both JS and D3, and I've googled this a tonne but only found examples that are a bit too advanced.

I'm making a simple decision graph implementation, and I'm stuck trying to connect 2 nodes with a line / path. The objects can be moved around with the mouse, and the path should always update to reflect the positions of the objects.

This is my base source of knowledge: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes, but I don't quite understand how to do something smart with it.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/AXEFERo/5/edit

Don't need the fancy stuff, just need to understand how to create connectors and have them update dynamically when the objects are being dragged around. Big thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To draw a line between the circles, you don't need anything special -- just the `line` element.

```
var line = svg.append("line")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .attr("x1", 150)
        .attr("y1", 100)
        .attr("x2", 250)
        .attr("y2", 300);
```

Updating the position dynamically is a bit more difficult. At the moment, you have no means of distinguishing which of the circles is being dragged. One way of doing this is to add a distinguishing class to the `g` elements.

```
var g1 = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 150 + "," + 100 + ")")
        .attr("class", "first")
        ...
```

and similarly for the other one. Now you can switch on the class in your `dragmove` function and update either the start or the end coordinates of the line.

```
if(d3.select(this).attr("class") == "first") {
            line.attr("x1", x);
            line.attr("y1", y);
} else {
            line.attr("x2", x);
            line.attr("y2", y);
}
```

Complete example [here](http://jsbin.com/UhokUTu/1/edit). There are other, more elegant ways of achieving this. In a real application, you would have data bound to the elements and could use that to distinguish between the different circles.

Comment: Great, just the basics I wanted! The "more elegant ways", would they have a similar principal or are they completely different? Do you have any relevant links or keywords relating to that? Thanks again...

Comment: The principle would be the same. Have a look at [the force-directed layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) for a more advanced example.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this is a clean and useful example, but I can't see why you're using the g elements here. Why not use the circles directly to add classes first etc? As it is this approach implies a group per element which kinda eliminates the whole point of groups as well, would not it? There is probably an implicit reference to a best practice here, but I can't see it. Could you comment please?

Comment: @sarikan You're right that there's no need to for groups in this specific example, you could use just the circles.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks a lot for such a prompt response!

Comment: is there any way to let you add the connection by dragging the source node to the target node